# Trying to create a SQL query for a repair database

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagrip

I am trying to create a query that returns the list of works performed by ewere or Daria in the period from 01.01.2014 to 01.02.2014 or in the period from 01.05.2014 to 01.06.2014 or basically any date period.

The list must contain a description of the work, the name of the worker, the date of the work. The list must be sorted by ascending date of work.

[Operations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KletS.png)

[worker table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeQXU.png)

This is what I have tried, as I am new to SQL and trying to understand:

```
Select 
    tblOperation.datOperationDate, 
    tblOperation.txtOperationDescription,
    tblWorker.txtWorkerName, tblWorker.intWorkerId
From 
    tblOperation
Inner join 
    tblWorker on tblOperation.intWorkerId = tblWorker.intWorkerId
Where 
    ((('2000-08-20' < tblOperation.datOperationDate) and 
      ('2012-02-20' < tblOperation.datOperationDate)) or
     (('2010-01-24' < tblOperation.datOperationDate) and  
      ('2018-01-13' < tblOperation.datOperationDate))) and
    (tblOperation.txtOperationDescription = true) and 
    (tblWorker..txtWorkerName = 'ewere') or 
    (tblWorker..txtWorkerName = 'Daria')
Order by 
    tblOperation.datOperationDate
```

Comment: Although I addded a reply, instead of pictures you should add your sample as text. In datagrip, where you see 'SQL Inserts', select 'SQL Insert - Multirow' and clicking downarrow select copy to clipboard to get the data as insert (limiting to less rows, 500 might be too much to post here). Add table create scripts too. Also, from your datagrip view it is SQL server, but you should add it to your tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your date range is overlapping and effectively means (if were written correctly) between '2000-08-21' and '2018-01-12'. For description, probably you meant those that are not null, it is not a boolean field and in SQL server booleans are bit (0 or 1):

```
Select tblOperation.datOperationDate, tblOperation.txtOperationDescription,tblWorker.txtWorkerName ,tblWorker.intWorkerId
From tblOperation
Inner join tblWorker on tblOperation.intWorkerId = tblWorker.intWorkerId
Where 
    tblOperation.datOperationDate between '20000821' and '20180112' and
    tblOperation.txtOperationDescription is not null and 
    tblWorker.txtWorkerName in ('ewere','Daria')
Order by tblOperation.datOperationDate;
```

Comment: it works but I need two date ranges as in the question which are also separated using the OR and I also need to use OR in the name of workers if possible

Comment: @wily.x.x, you can do that. Since your dates were overlapping I connected them. Then you should correct your expression, if you look at what you have written closely you were effectively saying  date > '2012-02-20'.  ( tblOperation.datOperationDate > '2000-08-20' and '2018-01-12' and  tblOperation.datOperationDate < '2012-02-20' ) or ... would be correct for the first range. If they overlap, connect them.